# Password Hashing SELECT (PHP)

Tags: hash, mysql, salt

Is it possible to select a hashed and salted password from MySql DB only using the posted password? If so, how?

If I hash the password this way:

```
    $password = "blabla";
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

`$hash` will be, for example, `$2y$10$8zzd3lj6oIPlBPnCxsU7nOmtsEFlKw/BdqTXyMgbuojjVpiEe4rVm` and it will be stored in the db.

How, during a login, do I check against the hashed password column only, and only table's column, if the passwords match, having only 'blabla' as data?

Comment: Sure, just hash the password with all salts stored in the db and compare it to the stored hash; this would run in O(#users) - if each user has their own salt -, which might be ok. But why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: Welcome. Is your how about PHP programming or something else ?

Comment: If you have access to the hashing method and the salt, and you have SELECT access to the database. There are a lot of pre-conditions and you don't offer a lot of details in your question. Is PHP a crucial component? Is MySQL? Do you only have client access or do you also have server access?

Comment: You mean as a normal part of the server's login process? Why do you need to know what `$password` was?

Comment: By using `password_verify`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking and you are ignoring the comments.

Comment: @begueradj Rewriting my question: can I say if a plain text string matches a hashed and salted string. Given only 'blabla', can I tell that it matches $2y$10$8zzd3lj6oIPlBPnCxsU7nOmtsEFlKw/BdqTXyMgbuojjVpiEe4rVm?

Comment: Are you asking how a login process uses hashes to verify the user-supplied password?

Comment: @schroeder Simplified: You have ONLY ONE column named "hashedpassword". Check against this column if a plain given text ('blabla') machtes one of the hashes stored in it. Can it be done?

Comment: OK - I think we boiled down your question. This is a basic login process question and best asked over at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A properly salted and hashed password cannot be searched for with a database query. You will have to search for the hash by username/email/... and afterwards you can verify the entered password with the found hash.

1) First query for the stored hash

```
SELECT passwordhash FROM users WHERE email = ?
```

2) Verify the entered password with the found hash

```
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

It is the salt who makes the search impossible, it must be extracted from the stored hash *before* you can verify the password. Such a query would have to read each hash, extract its salt and do the hashing. Because the hash function is very slow (on purpose) the query would need ways too long to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean how to select a hashed and salted password from a database then verify it with a plaintext password?  If so, here is how with bcrypt.

Keep in mind, this requires PHP 5 >= 5.5.0.

Also, I recommend [scrypt](https://github.com/DomBlack/php-scrypt) over bcrypt, but you have to install scrypt manually.

SQL stuff

```
CREATE DATABASE `example`;
USE `example`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `username` VARCHAR(16),
    `password` VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Hash Class (classes/Hash.class.php)

```
<?php
class Hash
{
    public static function make($string)
    {
        $options = array('cost' => 11);
        return password_hash($string, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)
    }

    public static function check($password, $hash)
    {
        return password_verify($password, $hash);
    }
}
```

Database Class (classes/DB.class.php)

```
<?php
class DB
{
    private $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
    private $dbname = 'example';
    private $dbuser = 'root';
    private $dbpass = 'pass';

    public function Connect()
    {
        return new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbhost . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->dbuser, $this->pass);
    }
}
```

User Class (classes/User.class.php)

```
<?php
require_once('DB.class.php');
require_once('Hash.class.php');

class User
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new DB();
        $this->db = $this->db->Connect();
    }

    public function find($username)
    {
        $st = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username LIMIT 1');
        $st->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();

        if($st->rowCount())
        {
            return $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function create($username, $password)
    {
        $password = Hash::make($password);

        $st = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`) VALUES (:username, :password)');
        $st->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();
    }

    public function verify($username, $password)
    {
        $user = $this->find($username);

        if($user)
        {
            if(Hash::check($password, $user['password']))
            {
                $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['isLoggedIn']))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Registration (register.php)

```
<?php
require_once('classes/User.class.php');

$user = new User();

if($user->isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Check if username and password exist
    if(!isset($username) || !isset($password))
    {
        die('Username and password required');
    }

    // Check if values are not empty
    if(empty($username) || empty($password))
    {
        die('Blank fields not allowed');
    }


    // Check if username length is in between 4 and 16
    if(strlen($username) < 4 && strlen($username) > 16)
    {
        die('Username must be in between 4 and 16 characters');
    }

    // Check if username is alphanumeric
    if(!ctype_alnum($username))
    {
        die('Username must be alphanumeric');
    }

    // Check password length
    if(strlen($password) < 8)
    {
        die('Passwords should be at least 8 characters long');
    }

    // Check if username exists
    $exists = $user->find($username);

    if($exists)
    {
        die('Username already in use');
    }

    // Create account
    $user->create($username, $password);
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();

}
?>

// HTML goes here
```

Login (login.php)

```
<?php
require_once('classes/User.class.php');

$user = new User();

if($user->isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Check if username and password exist
    if(!isset($username) || !isset($password))
    {
        die('Username and password required');
    }

    // Check if values are not empty
    if(empty($username) || empty($password))
    {
        die('Blank fields not allowed');
    }


    // Check if username length is in between 4 and 16
    if(strlen($username) < 4 && strlen($username) > 16)
    {
        die('Username must be in between 4 and 16 characters');
    }

    // Check if username is alphanumeric
    if(!ctype_alnum($username))
    {
        die('Username must be alphanumeric');
    }

    // Check password length
    if(strlen($password) < 8)
    {
        die('Passwords should be at least 8 characters long');
    }

    // Try to login
    $verified = $user->verify($username, $password);

    if($verified)
    {
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
    } else {
        die('Invalid username/password');
    }
}
?>

// HTML goes here
```

Logout (logout.php)

```
<?php
require_once('classes/User.class.php');

$user = new User();

if($user->isLoggedIn())
{
    unset($_SESSION['isLoggedIn']);
}

header('Location: login.php');
die();
```

Index (index.php)

```
<?php
require_once('classes/User.class.php');

if(!$user->isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Welcome</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout?</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Simon I didn't say anything was wrong with bcrypt, I said "I recommend scrypt over bcrypt, but you have to install scrypt manually."

Comment: Fine then, I will rephrase. Why would you recommend scrypt over bcrypt?

Comment: @Simon While bcrypt is older than scrypt, scrypt allows you to set the amount of space in memory that it will use while bcrypt does not.  Also, see [this](https://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html)

Comment: Just a nitpick, your `check` function in the `Hash` class could be simplified to `return password_verify($password, $hash);`.

Answer (score 0):

> How, during a login, do I check against the hashed password column only, and only table's column, if the passwords match, having only 'blabla' as data?

You can't. Password storage is designed to make many operations impossible. If you want to find a match for a password without using the user name or some other key, you will need to call `password_verify` on every password until you get a match. By design, this will be very slow.

Being passwords don't need to be in unique, you may have one password that matches many entries.

My guess is that this is a bad idea and not what you want.